# Meaning and usage of the word "Unchainable"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I'd like to use the word "unchainable" in the context of a short novel, but I see that such a word is not popular. Plus maybe its meaning could be misunderstood, as I want it to mean "that cannot be chained", and refer it to a person. An expedient to mean "no chain can tie her up", with one only word, and maybe also in a somehow poetic sense/ license.

What do you think? Would you understand it as I mean it? Other suggestions?

Comment: Chains don't tie people up; chains bind people, the metaphor. To be bound by chains. You tie people up with a rope or cord. Perhaps you are trying to say: no ties bind her to him or to her family. She has no binding ties. The chain thing sounds quasi-s&m to me....just saying.

Comment: The word is ambiguous. It can mean 'not chainable', i.e something that cannot be chained, but it can also mean 'able to be unchained', i.e, something can be unchained. One is parsed [un-[chain-able]], and the other [[un-chain]-able]. Similar remarks apply to _unlockable_; this is not an isolated occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

**unchainable**  A good word, less usage is good too, many would understand it and it is appropriate for literary use.

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unchainable)

> That cannot be chained.

Answer (score 0):

[**Unstoppable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unstoppable):

> incapable of being defeated, overcome, or subdued · At this point
>   she's so far ahead in the polls that she's unstoppable.

[**Uncontrollable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncontrollable):

> incapable of being controlled : UNGOVERNABLE